# Secure File Transfer

Tags: c#, security

Right now I'm looking for a way to securely transfer a file between a client and a server in c#.  I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Basically, I'm looking preferably for a library, if not that a technique I can do this. It is worth bearing in mind I have to do both the client and the server for this. The language I'm using is c# so everything will either be on windows or using mono.

Comment: HTTPS provides secure encryption and is generally available, FTP/SFTP port are often not available. Just put the file contents in the POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About library, you can take a look at [WinSCP .NET Assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).
It's a simple wrapper around WinSCP and you can easily implement a small but fully functional FTP/SFTP client over it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need not one, but two things.

1. A server to act as a storage place for files to be uploaded to and downloaded from
2. Code to help your code interact with the aforementioned server.

For the server, I'd suggest an FTP server. You can either setup your own or pay a 3rd-party provider to host one for you. So that the FTP server is accessed securely, you'll want to specify FTPS or SFTP protocols for the connections it accepts. Both of these provide encrypted end-to-end communication channels between the client and the server.

Windows Server includes and FTP server.  It supports FTPS, but it does not support SFTP.  If you want/need to use SFTP, there are 3rd-party FTP servers available for Windows that support it.

Regarding code to access the server, there are numerous .NET libraries available.  You can build it from scratch using .NET, or you can buy software components, such as [ChilKat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj28u-92qDXAhWrx4MKHa9pCUYQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chilkatsoft.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1E1n8fSAjyefKdbXXKUcKz) or [EnterpriseDT](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv9sra2qDXAhWD14MKHWD5BH0QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fenterprisedt.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2GtlpDgkKIAC1IF1UBhxvq).  I have had a good experience using both. There are others available, I'm sure.

There is probably no need to reinvent what will turn out to be a pretty expensive wheel.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking. Unfortunately (unless my google searches are using the wrong keywords), I can't seem to find a decent sftp or ftps server library. The one I did find had not documentation and looked pretty old so I decided against it. So part of the question is (as I stated above) do you know a library that can help me with this.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: The programming language is mentioned in the tags, but I'll edit it to the question.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see that `C#` tag!